# How do I capture action button back from SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

how can I capture the back arrow command in Android `SearchView`.

need to hide the previously opened list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setOnActionExpandListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnActionExpandListener(android.view.MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener)) of MenuItem

```
mSearchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
                //TODO Here you can do your list hiding stuff :D
                return true;
            }
        });
```